# inserting row(s) from the selected value

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 columns A and B.

```
A = 12 (months)
B = 12.000.000
C (result) = B/A = 12.000.000 / 12 = 1.000.000
```

The result that I want will be looping automatically insert new row(s) based on months (A)

```
month     amount
1        1.000.000
2        1.000.000
3        1.000.000
4        1.000.000
5        1.000.000
6        1.000.000
.
.
.
12       1.000.000
```

this is my complete code while adding in my case :

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lPart As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("PostBudgetData")

lRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

lPart = Me.cboMonth.ListIndex
    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
    If Trim(Me.cboMonth.Value) = "" Then
        Me.cboMonth.SetFocus
        MsgBox "Please enter a part number"
    Exit Sub
    End If
End If



'copy the data to the database
With ws
  .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = Me.cboYear.Value
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
      .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = Me.cboMonth.List(lPart, 0)
End If
  .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = Me.cboBrand.Value
  .Cells(lRow, 4).Value = Me.cboPostBudget.Value
  .Cells(lRow, 5).Value = Me.cboArea.Value
  .Cells(lRow, 6).Value = Me.txtValue.Value
  .Cells(lRow, 7).Value = Me.cboSBU.Value
End With

'clear the data
Me.cboMonth.Value = ""
Me.cboYear.Value = ""
Me.cboBrand.Value = ""
Me.cboPostBudget.Value = ""
Me.cboArea.Value = ""
Me.cboSBU.Value = ""

'Me.txtValue.Value = Format(Date, "Medium Date")
Me.txtValue.Value = 0

If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
      Me.cboMonth.SetFocus
End If

End Sub
```

But it is not looping. I don't know to loop in vba while inserting new row(s) cos it just insert 1 row. This is what i tried not just I'm tired and asking without do anything.

Comment: The best way to get help here is to first try something. If you get stuck, do some research, make an attempt at fixing things yourself, and only then ask a specific question about your attempts, showing what you have tried. Questions asking for complete solutions without demonstrating research effort usually get downvoted and closed.

Comment: I would just add an (Excel table)[https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Create-or-delete-an-Excel-table-in-a-worksheet-867f3add-0522-493c-94ab-b1b9933f46ca]. They trigger the event and pull down your formula any time a new value is entered without the nasty side-effects of VBA (blocked etc.). Works on workbooks that are not shared ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This VBA code takes values from cells `A2` and `B2` and generates the new rows on columns `D` and `E`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    first_column = 4 'first column of results
    total_months = Cells(2, 1) 'cell of total months
    total_amount = Cells(2, 2) 'cell of total amount
    calculated_value = total_amount / total_months
    changed = False
    Dim a As Range
    Select Case Target.Address
        Case "$A$2"
            changed = True
        Case "$B$2"
            changed = True
    End Select
    If changed = True Then 'only updates if change cells A2 or B2
        Columns(first_column).ClearContents
        Columns(first_column + 1).ClearContents
        Cells(1, first_column) = "month"
        Cells(1, first_column + 1) = "amount"
        For i = 2 To total_months + 1 ' loop the number of rows=totalmonths
            Cells(i, first_column) = i - 1
            Cells(i, first_column + 1) = calculated_value
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

You have to copy the code, go to View -> Macros in Excel, create a new one (any name is valid) and on the left column double click the worksheet where you want to use it (**red flag in the picture**) and in the right side, paste the code.

[image: VBA Macro on Sheet]

This is the way it looks:

[image: excel_rows]

Answer (score 0):

If all you are looking for is how to loop in vba then this might help you:

```
'12 = times you want to loop
For i = 1 to 12 

'inserts row before row number i
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Rows(i).Insert
'fill cells with content
Sheets(1).Cells(i,1) = <something

'loop 
Next i
```